# Passing void pointer through function and casting later to the wanted type

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I'm practicing C and I'm still not very safe by using pointers. Down there I wrote a code (didn't compile it, just as pseudo)
Let's say I have something like:

```
typedef struct
{
   uint16 A;
   uint16 B
   uint16 C;
   uint16 D;
   uint16 E
}myDataStruct;

typedef struct _data_info
{
    uint8t*           bufAddr;
    uint32t           bufSize;

}data_info;


int getInfo(void* pMsg, int32 size); //pMsg points to the buffer of the message and size is the size of the buffer. This function receives a message from a message queue and is defined in the OS. It is similar like an mq_receive() known from Posix


static void myFunction(void* pData);

static void OperateOnData(myDataStruct* pData)


main()
{
    data_info inf;   //Declare instance of data_info

    getInfo(&inf,sizeof(data_info))   //Function holds the information where data of interest is stored

    myFunction((void*)data_info.bufAddr);  //Here I want to pass the address of the data in order to operate on it
}

static void myFunction(void* pData)
{ 
  /*Furtheremore I want to pass the pointer to next function where the data will be used*/
  OperateOnData((myDataStruct*)pData)
}

static void OperateOnData(myDataStruct* pData)
{
    /*do something with pData*/

    uint8 x;
    uint8 y;

    x = pData->A
    Y = pData->B 

 /*....*/
 /*....*/
}
```

The question here is did I correctly provided the data from the call of myFunction() down to
OperateOnData() function so I can use the data which is hold in the address returned by getInfo().Is it ok to have the parameter of myFunction as *void and than later to cast it to the wanted type like myDataStruct ?

Comment: If `data_info.bufAddr` points to a dynamically allocated memory object that was accessed as a `myDataStruct` then it is fine, assuming the alignment size of `uint8t` is 1.

Comment: "didn't compile it" Why not? That would have told you about at least one bug

Comment: @wohlstad: Thanks I corrected this. I will assume the type is not know at the point when calling the function. Therefore I provide the void pointer.

Comment: Is `VOID` something special or is it just `void` ?

Comment: @SupportUkraine I fixed it : Instead of pData.A it is pData->A. And VOID is just void

Comment: `getInfo(&inf,sizeof(data_info))` What type will `sizeof` return? What type is `getInfo` expecting for the second parameter?

Comment: @SupportUkraine It returns an uint32. It expects the size of data_info.

Comment: It's kind of pointless to discuss if your pseudo code is "correct" - it obviously isn't. What matters here is what underlying problem you are trying to solve - some manner of type generic allocator? Creating an "ADT" struct with various related functions? Something else?

Comment: "_Passing void pointer through function and casting later to the wanted type_" Suggest you search out and read some Q&A here on SO about using Standard Library function`qsort()`...

Comment: @JohnDoe Look at: `int getInfo(VOID * pMsg, int32 *size);` The second parameter is a pointer to int32. It's not int32. BTW: `sizeof` returns `size_t`

Comment: Quote: " in the address returned by getInfo()" Well `getInfo` does not return an address. `getInfo` may update the values of the member of `inf`. But strictly that isn't a return value. `getInfo` returns an `int` which is being ignored by your code.

Comment: Can you provide the definition of `getInfo`? Overall, we need some code that compiles ([mcve]).

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre]. (That is standard for debugging questions, and while this question might not specifically be a debugging question, a [mre] is suitable for it.) In particular, show the definition of `uint8t` and a sample implementation of `grtInfo`. The fact that `bufAddr` is declared as `uint8t *` instead of `void *` may raise some technical issues, but the code may otherwise be fine.

Comment: I updated the description. The second parameter of int getInfo(void* pMsg, int32 size) is not a pointer! I tried to minimalize the example as much as possible but I see it introduces mistakes. So I can say that getInfo is meant like mq_receive() known from POSIX

Comment: The second parameter of `getInfo` seems very strange. What is it supposed to tell?

Comment: Also it's unclear what `bufSize` is supposed to tell. What if `bufSize` is less than `sizeof(myDataStruct)`?  What if `bufSize` is bigger than `sizeof(myDataStruct)`?

Comment: There are a number of things which is unclear to me (see previous comments). What you are doing may or may not be okay. That `myDataStruct` only has `uint8` members increase the chance of this being okay as won't have alignment problems.

Comment: @SupportUkraine You are right, let's say it has 5 u16 elements. In that case could it be problematic?

Comment: @JohnDoe Without a more detailed description what the "size" member and "size" parameter means, it can't tell whether this will work.

Comment: Please provide code one can compile. Use also the ' #include' s. And note that the types from `stdint`  are all wrong. Do you really need a signed `size`?

Comment: @JohnDoe: You have written several times that you are converting the pointer back to the original type, `myDataStruct *`. However, if `getInfo` gets the address of a communication buffer defined as an array of character type or of some address within it, then converting that address to `myDataStruct *` does not convert back to the original type because the original type is an array of character type, not a `myDataStruct`. If so, your code is not portable C code. You should edit the question to provide a [mre], and it should be voted down and closed until that is done.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking pointer punning is dangerous and you should use `memcpy` to be safe and you will not invoke undefined behaviour.

```
static void myFunction(void* pData)
{ 
    myDataStruct Data;
    memcpy(&Data, pData, sizeof(Data));
    OperateOnData(&Data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> did I correctly provided the data from the call of `myFunction()` down to `OperateOnData()` function so I can use the data which is hold in the address returned by `getInfo()`(?)

Not certainly.

`myFunction((void*)data_info.bufAddr);` (more simply coded as `myFunction(data_info.bufAddr);` as the cast is not needed going to `void *`) does pass a pointer, but `myFunction()` lacks information on how much of the data pointed to by `data_info.bufAddr` is valid to use.

---

> Is it ok to have the parameter of `myFunction` as `*void` and <strike>than</strike> then later to cast it to the wanted type like `myDataStruct`?

Yes it is *OK*.   Note the cast is not needed to go from `void *` to `myDataStruct *`.

---

There are other considerations involved when defeating type checking.  Without knowing OP's higher level goals, it remains unclear on how to advise for a good alternative.

Sometime type defeating is good.  Usually it is not.

Answer (score 0):

The code as posted has many many problems. Consider at least:

- `main` returns an `int`
- the use of `static` for the functions  will work against you, since you cannot simply write `stuff.h`/`stuff.c` and test it using a dozen of small programs with just `main`... If you really need this you can add in another time.
- all types from `stdint` are wrong. Try `uint8_t` and not `uint8t` as an example
- avoid using types starting with underscores, ever. They are *reserved*  for use in libraries
- use the convention of naming `typedef`'ed things with a starting uppercase letter
- avoid camelCase stuff :) it is a java thing
- let the `struct` anonymous if there no internal self-references

```
typedef struct _data_info
{
    uint8t*           addr;
    uint32t           size;
}data_info;
```

Could be

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t*          addr;
    uint32_t          size;
}  Info;
```

In `myFunction` you pass a pointer to a thing, not the `typedef` name, so

```
myFunction(
        (void*)data_info.bufAddr);
```

should be

```
        myFunction((void*)inf);
```

or something similar. And is probably sill wrong:
You declared

```
int getInfo(void* pMsg, int32_t size);
```

But the name suggests you are *receiving* something so the usual is that the function will allocate a buffer of the `info` thing and return it. Since you are passing a value to `getInfo` you will not get the `size` value back. `size` should be also a pointer.

And even this is not good. The usual in `C` is

```
        Info* get_info();
```

This way you just get --- guess what? --- a pointer to some info.

- do not use `void` if you have an idea of the type a thing could have.  `void` is *no friend*.
- do not return `void`: return a status code, or a pointer to a named thing the compiler could check for you.
- a cast is many times irrelevant to the compiler, but it is a warning, a piece of documentation to the reader of the code, for you in the next day.
  It can save you a lot of trouble if you for example `malloc` 4 types of buffers in a function and cast all returned `void*` things to the type you expect, may be half a dozen times: one can call it waste of typing, other can call it insurance. A bug in inverting a pair of these pointers can cost you a day, a job, who knows? Only in students code the `malloc` argument is a thing as simple as a `n * sizeof(t)`. In production code many times the `size` is the result of a complex expression or even a function call, like `malloc(f())`. Just by looking at the call itself you may not be able to see a bug for inverting some allocations...

### Your code in a way that almost compile

This serves as basis for what we are talking here

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
  uint16_t            A;
  uint16_t            B;
  uint16_t            C;
  uint16_t            D;
  uint16_t            E;
} myDataStruct;

typedef struct _data_info
{
  uint8_t*  bufAddr;
  uint32_t bufSize;

} data_info;

int getInfo(
  void* pMsg,
  int32_t size);  // pMsg points to the buffer of the
                // message and size is the size of the
                // buffer. This function receives a
                // message from a message queue and is
                // defined in the OS. It is similar like
                // an mq_receive() known from Posix

static void myFunction(void* pData);

static void OperateOnData(myDataStruct* pData);

int main(void)
{
  data_info inf;  // Declare instance of data_info

  getInfo(&inf.bufAddr,inf.bufSize);  // Function holds the
                           // information
                       // where data of interest is stored

      myFunction(
          &inf);  // Here I want to pass the
                          // address of the data in order
                          // to operate on it
}

static void myFunction(void* pData)
{
      /*Furtheremore I want to pass the pointer to next
       * function where the data will be used*/
      OperateOnData((myDataStruct*)pData);
};

static void OperateOnData(myDataStruct* pData)
{
      /*do something with pData*/

      uint8_t x;
      uint8_t y;

      // x = pData->A Y = pData->B

      /*....*/
      /*....*/
};
```

### an example

I will add example code on a common way to process this kind of messages, with complete commented code

#### the data

```
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t size;
    uint8_t* addr;
} Info;

Info* free_info(Info*);
Info* get_info();
int   my_fn1(Info* data);
int   my_fn2(Info* data);
int   operate_on(Info*[], int (*fn)(Info*));
int   show_info(Info* data, const char* msg);
```

A possible implementation of all them is at the end

`Info` is the packet. `get_info()` here is a factory function that returns a random short message with 10 to 50 bytes, 90% of them with up to 20, so we can test at easy. It is inside `get_info` where you would call `mq_receive()`.

#### `my_fn1` and `my_fn2`

This functions just mark the messages with "f1","F1","f2" or "F2" for easy testing.

#### `show_info`

This one just shows an `Info` message on screen with an optional text.

#### `operate_on` is like a javascript `forEach`

In networking is common to receive messages as a stream of pointers, with a `NULL` marking the end. This is what `operate_on` does: it takes an array of pointers and process thru the supplied function. It is like what `forEach` method does for an Array in javascript, or `std:for_each` does in `C++`

```
int operate_on(Info* data[], int (*fn)(Info*))
{
    if (data == NULL) return -1;
    size_t i = 0;
    Info**  p = (Info**)data;
    while (*p != NULL) fn(*p++);
    return 0;
}
```

And it is not much. For testing this I wrote the mininum 2 functions. Here is `operate_on` in use as in the example:

```
    Info*     block[9] = {0};
    const int tst_size =
        sizeof(block) / sizeof(block[0]) - 1;
    int res = 0;
    printf("\t%d messages in this test\n", tst_size);
    for (int i = 0; i < tst_size; i += 1)
        block[i] = get_info(), show_info(block[i], "[new] ");
    block[tst_size] = NULL;

    res = operate_on(block, my_fn1);
    res = operate_on(block, my_fn2);

    for (int i = 0; i < tst_size; i += 1)
        show_info(block[i], NULL);
```

You just pass 2 pointers: one for the array of messages, other for the function address

**`C` was written for this kind of task.**

#### `main` for a test

```
{
    srand(230913);
    Info*     block[9] = {0};
    const int tst_size =
        sizeof(block) / sizeof(block[0]) - 1;
    int res = 0;
    printf("\t%d messages in this test\n", tst_size);
    for (int i = 0; i < tst_size; i += 1)
        block[i] = get_info(),
        show_info(block[i], "[new] ");
    block[tst_size] = NULL;

    // call f1 f2
    printf("\tCall my_fn1() for all messages\n");
    res = operate_on(block, my_fn1);
    printf("\tCall my_fn2() for all messages\n");
    res = operate_on(block, my_fn2);
    printf("\tShow all %d messages\n", tst_size);
    for (int i = 0; i < tst_size; i += 1)
        show_info(block[i], NULL);

    // again
    printf("\tCall my_fn1() for all messages\n");
    res = operate_on(block, my_fn1);
    printf("\tCall my_fn2() for all messages\n");
    res = operate_on(block, my_fn2);
    printf("\tShow all %d messages\n", tst_size);
    for (int i = 0; i < tst_size; i += 1)
        show_info(block[i], NULL);

    // free all
    for (int i = 0; i < tst_size; i += 1) free(block[i]);
    return 0;
};
```

The code

- builds an array of `Info` messages by calling `get_info`
- shows the messages on-screen
- uses `operate_on` to pass all messages by `my_fn1` and `my_fn2`
- shows the processed results
- clears everything

#### output

```
        8 messages in this test
[new] ====> [35 bytes]  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec"
[new] ====> [16 bytes]  "Lorem ipsum dol"
[new] ====> [33 bytes]  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cons"
[new] ====> [12 bytes]  "Lorem ipsum"
[new] ====> [16 bytes]  "Lorem ipsum dol"
[new] ====> [36 bytes]  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consect"
[new] ====> [16 bytes]  "Lorem ipsum dol"
[new] ====> [17 bytes]  "Lorem ipsum dolo"
        Call my_fn1() for all messages
        Call my_fn2() for all messages
        Show all 8 messages
====> [35 bytes]        "F1F2m ipsum dolor sit amet, consec"
====> [16 bytes]        "F1F2m ipsum dol"
====> [33 bytes]        "F1F2m ipsum dolor sit amet, cons"
====> [12 bytes]        "F1F2m ipsum"
====> [16 bytes]        "F1F2m ipsum dol"
====> [36 bytes]        "F1F2m ipsum dolor sit amet, consect"
====> [16 bytes]        "F1F2m ipsum dol"
====> [17 bytes]        "F1F2m ipsum dolo"
        Call my_fn1() for all messages
        Call my_fn2() for all messages
        Show all 8 messages
====> [35 bytes]        "f1f2m ipsum dolor sit amet, consec"
====> [16 bytes]        "f1f2m ipsum dol"
====> [33 bytes]        "f1f2m ipsum dolor sit amet, cons"
====> [12 bytes]        "f1f2m ipsum"
====> [16 bytes]        "f1f2m ipsum dol"
====> [36 bytes]        "f1f2m ipsum dolor sit amet, consect"
====> [16 bytes]        "f1f2m ipsum dol"
====> [17 bytes]        "f1f2m ipsum dolo"
```

#### complete code

```
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t size;
    uint8_t* addr;
} Info;

Info* free_info(Info*);
Info* get_info();
int   my_fn1(Info* data);
int   my_fn2(Info* data);
int   operate_on(Info*[], int (*fn)(Info*));
int   show_info(Info* data, const char* msg);

int main(void)
{
    srand(230913);
    Info*     block[9] = {0};
    const int tst_size =
        sizeof(block) / sizeof(block[0]) - 1;
    int res = 0;
    printf("\t%d messages in this test\n", tst_size);
    for (int i = 0; i < tst_size; i += 1)
        block[i] = get_info(),
        show_info(block[i], "[new] ");
    block[tst_size] = NULL;

    // call f1 f2
    printf("\tCall my_fn1() for all messages\n");
    res = operate_on(block, my_fn1);
    printf("\tCall my_fn2() for all messages\n");
    res = operate_on(block, my_fn2);
    printf("\tShow all %d messages\n", tst_size);
    for (int i = 0; i < tst_size; i += 1)
        show_info(block[i], NULL);

    // again
    printf("\tCall my_fn1() for all messages\n");
    res = operate_on(block, my_fn1);
    printf("\tCall my_fn2() for all messages\n");
    res = operate_on(block, my_fn2);
    printf("\tShow all %d messages\n", tst_size);
    for (int i = 0; i < tst_size; i += 1)
        show_info(block[i], NULL);

    // free all
    for (int i = 0; i < tst_size; i += 1) free(block[i]);
    return 0;
};

Info* free_info(Info* info)
{
    if (info == NULL) return NULL;
    free(info->addr);
    free(info);
    return NULL;  // to invalidate the pointer
}

Info* get_info()
{
    // if it is the case, here is the place to call
    // mq_receive() and use the received data to fill
    // our `Info` buffer

    // by courtesy of lipsum.com
    const char* lorem =
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur "
        "adipiscing elit. Proin ornare, felis et tristique "
        "varius, libero eros tincidunt est, eleifend "
        "accumsan turpis magna eu elit. Donec quis "
        "vehicula quam. Phasellus sit amet convallis leo. "
        "Nullam sagittis egestas leo, et sagittis purus "
        "lobortis ut. Mauris a neque vitae diam elementum "
        "elementum quis";  // 336 bytes
    // now around 90% of the messages will have 10 to 20
    // bytes in size and the rest from 30 to 50 bytes
    Info* info = malloc(sizeof(Info));
    if (rand() % 10 < 9)
        info->size = rand() % 11 + 10;
    else
        info->size = rand() % 21 + 30;
    info->addr = malloc(info->size);
    memcpy(info->addr, lorem, info->size);
    *(info->addr + info->size - 1) = 0;  // we want a string
    return info;
}

int my_fn1(Info* data)
{
    if (data == NULL) return -1;
    switch (data->addr[0])
    {
        case 'F':
            data->addr[0] = 'f';
            data->addr[1] = '1';
            break;
        default:
            data->addr[0] = 'F';
            data->addr[1] = '1';
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

int my_fn2(Info* data)
{
    if (data == NULL) return -1;
    switch (data->addr[2])
    {
        case 'F':
            data->addr[2] = 'f';
            data->addr[3] = '2';
            break;
        default:
            data->addr[2] = 'F';
            data->addr[3] = '2';
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

int show_info(Info* data, const char* msg)
{
    if (data == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf(
        "====> [%u bytes]\t\"%s\"\n", data->size,
        data->addr);
    return 0;
}

int operate_on(Info* data[], int (*fn)(Info*))
{
    if (data == NULL) return -1;
    size_t i = 0;
    Info** p = (Info**)data;
    while (*p != NULL) fn(*p++);
    return 0;
}
```